# reduce dataframe between column values

Tags: python, dataframe

I would like to compute an operation between the intervals `col1 = 0, col2 = 1` and `col1 = 0, col2 = 2` the difference between the max and min value of the col3 of the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['id1','id1','id1','id1','id1','id1','id1','id1','id2','id2','id2','id2','id2','id2']
                  ,'col1':[0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0],'col2':[1,2,2,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,1,2,2,2],'col3':[11,12,13,14,11,22,33,11,12,13,14,11,22,33]})
```

## This would look like this:

```
    col1  col2  col3   id
 0     0     1    11  id1
 1     1     2    12  id1
 2     0     2    13  id1
 3     0     1    14  id1
 4     1     2    11  id1
 5     1     2    22  id1
 6     0     2    33  id1
 7     0     1    11  id2
 8     1     2    12  id2
 9     0     2    13  id2
 10    0     1    14  id2
 11    1     2    11  id2
 12    1     2    22  id2
 13    0     2    33  id2
```

Some info extra:

> when col 1 is 0 and col2 is 1, this means that is the begining of a
>   subset, when col 1 is 0 and col2 is 2 this means that is the end of a
>   subset to compute the operation with col3 values as previously
>   explained.

## Target

Obtain by id the different calculations between the intervals 0-1 and 0-2. In this way we would get something like:

```
# desired ouput
pd.DataFrame({'id':['id1','id1','id2','id2'], 'result':[2,22,2,22]})

    id  result
0  id1       2
1  id1      22
2  id2       2
3  id2      22
```

If we read the raw database as previously we would notice that it was in id1 there are two intervals id (0-1 and 0-2) in which we need to compute the max-min of col3 in the given interval. Besides, we have several ids , so at the end we would have all the results from the intervals between 0-1 and 0-2 with their respective id label.

Comment: Wouldn't rows 3-6 be counted as one block, where the max is 33 (row 6) and the min is 11 (row 4), resulting in 22 vs. 19 shown above?

Comment: @Brad Solomon , The question was partialy working, I have edited the question in the simplest way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answering your original question:

You could use `.groupby` with `.apply`:

```
def diffbetween(df):
    start = df[(df.col1 == 0) & (df.col2 == 1)].index[0]
    end = df[(df.col1 == 0) & (df.col2 == 2)].index[0]
    return df.loc[end].col3 - df.loc[start].col3

print(df.groupby('id').apply(diffbetween).to_frame(name='result').reset_index())
    id  result
0  id1       2
1  id2      19
```

**This is for cases in which you're looking for the specific values `col1 = 0`, `col2 = 1`, `col1 = 0`, and `col2 = 2`.**  If these will always be the min and max, respectively (if they won't be exceeded), then you should use @Alexander's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46199767/7954504).

#### Answering your new question:

```
import numpy as np
starts = df[(df.col1 == 0) & (df.col2 == 1)].index
ends = df[(df.col1 == 0) & (df.col2 == 2)].index

df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id', 'col3'], index=range(starts.shape[0]))
for i, (start, end) in enumerate(zip(starts, ends)):
    df2.iloc[i, 0] = df.iloc[end].id
    df2.iloc[i, 1] = np.ptp(df.iloc[start:end+1].col3)

print(df2)
    id col3
0  id1    2
1  id1   22
```

Comment: @PeCaDe is this the output you're looking for?  If not, just make sure to specify exactly what result you want in your question.

Answer (score 3):

As it appears that your `id` column already demarcates your groups, you don't even need to use `col1` or `col2`.

Just group on the `id` column and apply a lambda function that takes the difference between the max and min values in the group.

```
>>> df.groupby('id')['col3'].apply(lambda group: group.max() - group.min()).reset_index()
    id  col3
0  id1     2
1  id2    22
```

Comment: What is the logic to pick the `id` column value in the group?  I need to run now, but will look at this again later today.

Comment: the original dataset would have more id, so I would like to compute the operation all the blocks between diferent id and inside the same id. In this case i onle gave one id. because is the main problem

Comment: But there are multiple `id` values per group.  Should one assume that all the values would be identical in a given block (e.g. just use the first one)?  Or is it possible that a given block could have multiple values, in which case how does one choose?

Comment: One id has several pairs of (0,1) as begining and 0,2 as end, in which we would have to compute the difference between the max and min in each block (0,1 -- 0,2) and asign its id. At the end, we would have something like: id1 id1 id1 id2 id2 id2 ... idn  with their values(block value).